# Default number format in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, radgrid, right-to-left

I have `asp.net` page with a `radgrid` control containing a number field with a format such as

```
01/1250
02/2454
```

Some users see the number in the correct format and while others see it in a format such as

```
1250/01 
2454/02
```

The issue appears to be localised to Internet Explorer as fresh installs of Chrome and Firefox behave correctly. This leads me to believe there is a setting in Internet Explorer that may affect the format.

Comment: Have you tried setting a specific number format for the `radgrid` column?

Comment: Yes, I force the number format to be shown using LTR format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like IE is trying to format the number as a date.

Try setting your culture on the page or in your web.config

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx